# PHP Traversing Multi Dimensional (Array)Object

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an object that needs to be returned, however I need to perform some pre-return manipulation before returning it.

The object has the following format:

```
object(PaginationHelper)[3]
    public 'current_page' => int 1
    public 'items_per_page' => int 10
    public 'dataset' => 
        array (size=10)
            0 => 
                object(AdvertSet)[4]
                    public 'Keywords' => string '' (length=0)
                    protected 'Adverts' => 
                        array (size=3) // SIZE = 3 SO REMOVE THIS FROM 'dataset' ARRAY
                        ...
                    public 'LiveStatus' => boolean false
            1 => 
                object(AdvertSet)[5]
                    public 'Keywords' => string '' (length=0)
                    protected 'Adverts' => 
                        array (size=1) // SIZE = 1 SO KEEP THIS IN 'dataset' ARRAY
                        ...
                    public 'LiveStatus' => boolean false

      etc etc ....
[End Object]
```

**What I need to do:**

Remove all parts of the 'dataset' array that doesn't have an 'Adverts' count of 1, thereby preserving *only* those datasets that have an 'Adverts' array size of 1.
Retain the fact that it is an object, to be returned.

I've tried multi-dimensional recursive functions to get through this, however the fact that it's an object and not an array is making progress hard, and I'm not sure I would be able to convert from an object to an array and back again without messing up the object's internals.

Can anyone help with this? Here's what I've gotten so far with a foreach...

```
foreach($results as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'dataset') {
    // value is right array to check count
    foreach($value as $k => $v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
}
```

It doesn't work, but that's the method I'm currently working on.

I've also tried something like:

```
if(count($results->dataset->(Array)AdvertSet->Adverts == 1) { }
```

but I can't cast AdvertSet as Array.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Just a quick note: it doesn't have to be removed from the array, I just eventually need the same object without those that have an Adverts count of 3. So this could involve copying to a new array without those that have an Adverts count of <> 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was:

```
foreach($PaginationHelper->dataset as &$data) {
  if(count($data) !== 1)
     unset($data);
}
```

But after reading your question for the third time, I see you want to remove only those elements with a Adverts count not equal to 1.

Looking at your structure, the Adverts array is **protected**, and therefore there is now way to access it without *subclassing Advertset object*.

So, my final answer must be: It is **not possible** to remove them, with this structure!

Comment: i like the use of `&$data` + `unset`

Comment: @Alex LOL .. a common pitfall when in foreach is the missing &

Comment: I might not have clarified well enough, I'm looking to count (Object)PaginationHelper->(Array)dataset->(Object)AdvertSet->(Array)Adverts           - and then if Adverts has a count of 1, keep it, else remove that 'dataset'

Comment: Edited: I can create a new array with those that = 1, and return that as an object? Logic required still stands :)

Comment: As long as $Advertset->Adverts is protected, there is no chance to access that property.

Comment: @Jimbo, 2 questions appear now.. why do you want to remove that `Adverts` object if you can just skip processing it.. and second, are you sure it's a proper way to do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is *not* really recursive and you don't need recursive traversal.

You only need to iterate over the `$object->dataset` array and delete items where the count of adverts is not 1. Since you're trying to filter items over a protected property, one approach would be to implement a `AdvertSet::count()` method that would return number of contained adverts: `$object->dataset[$i]->Adverts->count() != 1`. I would advise against forcing your way to access the protected property just for the filtering's sake.

Comment: look again: Adverts is protected!

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Still you don't need recursive traversal, will update answer shortly.